# Contiguous allocation of objects using STL vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I need to create objects dynamically and would like to use vectors to do that. I understand that the pointers to the objects would be stored in the vector and they would be contiguous but the actual object will not be. I can do it as given in [Create objects in pre-allocated memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301043/create-objects-in-pre-allocated-memory) . However, I would prefer to use vectors. Is there any way I could do so?

Comment: Exact same thing. Just remember not to change the vector's size, because the memory is reallocated and it will cause all the pointers to those objects to invalidate.

Comment: Store objects instead of pointers in your vector and they are guaranteed to be contiguous.

Comment: If you use `vector<T>` instead of `vector<T*>` the objects will be laid out contiguously in memory.

Comment: yse a custom allocator that uses a contiguos memory?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247738/is-it-safe-to-assume-that-stl-vector-storage-is-always-contiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I need to create objects dynamically"*

Are you REALLY sure you NEED the dynamic allocation? If it is possible, use vector of objects instead:

```
std::vector<T> myObjects(100);
```

this allocates the single block of memory big enough to hold 100 instances of `T` and initializes them using the default constructor.

Comment: @Troy: Yet I believe that this is not the case. But I rephrased my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use custom allocator while creating the vector. Your allocator can pre-allocate memory the way you need it.